# Websocket on erlang misultin - always pass request to loop instead of ws_loop

Tags: javascript, websocket, erlang, misultin

It is so easy to set up websocket in misultin as follows.

```
start(Port) ->                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  misultin:start_link([
    {port, Port},
    {loop, fun(Req) -> handle_http(Req, Port) end},
    {ws_loop, fun(Ws) -> handle_websocket(Ws) end}
  ]).
```

However, in my javascript code `ws = new WebSocket("ws://url")` is always passed to `handle_http()` instead of `handle_websocket()`.

Is there any one know what did I miss?

Answer (score 3):

Misultin hasn't been maintained for the last 3 years.

It's possible that it doesn't support current websocket standards.

At some point, I ended up switching my systems from Misultin to [Cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy) due to websocket compatibility.
This may not be the issue you are having, but there's a good chance that it is.

Comment: Misultin author here. @david-budworth is on the spot, websockets have evolved considerably since I last released Misultin, and the current standard is simply not supported. Switch to Cowboy as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my Misultin version from 0.8 to 0.9, the problem is gone.
Version 0.8 claimed it support websocket but it seems not to really do.